# Error -206 creating Interbase stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, interbase

I am attempting to create a stored procedure using an IBConsole interactive SQL window. The intent of the procedure is to gather data from two tables, do some processing on that data, insert rows containing that data into a working table, then return the rows from the working table as the stored procedure result. The stored procedure:

```
SET TERM ^;
CREATE PROCEDURE BIBLIO_SUBJECT
RETURNS (ID INTEGER, SUBJECT VARCHAR(200))
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE CUR_SUBJECT VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE VARIABLE SUBJECT_LIST VARCHAR(500);
  DECLARE VARIABLE BIBLIOID INTEGER;
  DECLARE VARIABLE NEXTPOS INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM TSUBJECTS;
  FOR SELECT BIBLIO.ID, BIBLIO.SUBJECTS
    FROM BIBLIO
    WHERE BIBLIO.PUBLISH = TRUE
    INTO :BIBLIOID, :SUBJECT_LIST
  DO
  BEGIN
    SUBJECT_LIST = BIBLIO.SUBJECTS + ';';
    NEXTPOS = LOCATE(";", SUBJECT_LIST);
    WHILE (:NEXTPOS > 1) DO
    BEGIN
      CUR_SUBJECT = SUBSTR(:SUBJECT_LIST, 1, NEXTPOS - 1);
      SUBJECT_LIST = SUBSTR(:SUBJECT_LIST, NEXTPOS + 1, STRLEN(SUBJECT_LIST));
      INSERT INTO TSUBJECTS (SUBJECT, ID) VALUES(:CUR_SUBJECT, :BIBLIOID);
      NEXTPOS = LOCATE(";", SUBJECT_LIST);
    END
  END
  FOR SELECT BIBLIO_BEAST.BIBLIO_ID, BEAST.BEAST_NAME
    FROM BIBLIO_BEAST
    INNER JOIN BEAST ON (BEAST.ID = BIBLIO_BEAST.BEAST_ID)
    INNER JOIN BIBLIO ON (BIBLIO.ID = BIBLIO_BEAST.BIBLIO_ID)
    WHERE BIBLIO.PUBLISH = TRUE
    INTO :BIBLIOID, :CUR_SUBJECT
  DO
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TSUBJECTS (SUBJECT, ID) VALUES(:CUR_SUBJECT, :BIBLIOID);
  END

  FOR SELECT ID, SUBJECT
    FROM TSUBJECTS
    INTO :ID, :SUBJECT
  DO
    SUSPEND;
END^
SET TERM ;^
```

When I execute the above code in IBConsole I get the error:

```
Error at line 2
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
SQL - CREATE PROCEDURE BIBLIO_SUBJECT
RETURNS (ID INTEGER, SUBJECT VARCHAR(200))
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE CUR_SUBJECT VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE VARIABLE SUBJECT_LIST VARCHAR(500);
  DECLARE VARIABLE BIBLIOID INTEGER;
  DECLARE VARIABLE NEXTPOS INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM TSUBJECTS;
  FOR SELECT BIBLIO.ID, BIBLIO.SUBJECTS
    FROM BIBLIO
    WHERE BIBLIO.PUBLISH = TRUE
    INTO :BIBLIOID, :SUBJECT_LIST
  DO
  BEGIN
    SUBJECT_LIST = BIBLIO.SUBJECTS + ';';
    NEXTPOS = LOCATE(";", SUBJECT_LIST);
    WHILE (:NEXTPOS > 1) DO
    BEGIN
      CUR_SUBJECT = SUBSTR(:SUBJECT_LIST, 1, NEXTPOS - 1);
      SUBJECT_LIST = SUBSTR(:SUBJECT_LIST, NEXTPOS + 1, STRLEN(SUBJECT_LIST));
      INSERT INTO TSUBJECTS (SUBJECT, ID) VALUES(:CUR_SUBJECT, :BIBLIOID);
      NEXTPOS = LOCATE(";", SUBJECT_LIST);
    END
  END
  FOR SELECT BIBLIO_BEAST.BIBLIO_ID, BEAST.BEAST_NAME
    FROM BIBLIO_BEAST
    INNER JOIN BEAST ON (BEAST.ID = BIBLIO_BEAST.BEAST_ID)
    INNER JOIN BIBLIO ON (BIBLIO.ID = BIBLIO_BEAST.BIBLIO_ID)
    WHERE BIBLIO.PUBLISH = TRUE
    INTO :BIBLIOID, :CUR_SUBJECT
  DO
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TSUBJECTS (SUBJECT, ID) VALUES(:CUR_SUBJECT, :BIBLIOID);
  END

  FOR SELECT ID, SUBJECT
    FROM TSUBJECTS
    INTO :ID, :SUBJECT
  DO
    SUSPEND;
END
```

It doesn't say which column is "unknown", and line 2 is (apparently) the RETURNS clause of the CREATE PROCEDURE. Not at all helpful.

Each of the SQL statements in the stored procedure (3 SELECTs, a DELETE, 2 INSERTs) work without error if executed separately in an Interactive SQL window, so all of their columns are "known". BIBLIO_SUBJECT is not the name of an existing stored procedure, nor is it the name of an existing table, or anything else in the database.

This has me baffled. Online searches provide no answer. So I am hoping the clever Stack Overflow people can help me get this working.

David

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. It was the statement:

```
SUBJECT_LIST = BIBLIO.SUBJECTS + ';';
```

The SUBJECT_LIST variable is already used in the preceding select. A silly mistake, but I am old.

Not that it matters since the Interbase UDF functions Locate() and Substr() can only handle 80 character strings, which makes them really useless to me... and probably useless to most.